# Php\Ubuntu virtual links

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php4

I have latest Ubuntu 18, also Apache2, php 7.2, mysql.
I have rather old simple php application, written on php4 (at least not older than php5).
I have a task to run this application in this environment, to install php4 is not a variant. Possibly there are some compability mode to run this application by php7.2 as php4?

I succeded to open index.php in FireFox, but also it seems, that it is not shown correctly. I run that application also on Windows\IIS and it works perfectly. But on Ubuntu Application has a menu and i see only part of it. Also any item in that menu is created through localization links, like:
application\en\sitemap
application\en\news

Physically i have folders sitemap, news and etc, just under application root folder. But FireFox is not able to open application\en\news, because it seems it is trying to reach folder EN, which is not exist, of course. So neither menu item could be opened. Though on Windows it works from the start!

Tell me, please, direction for futher search. 
Is there a compability mode php7.2-php4?
How should this virtual links en-ru work - should i configure php or there should be some points in application config.php for this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried turning error_reporting on? I don't believe there is a compatibility mode for something that's three versions behind, you might have to start wading through the errors.

Comment: I turned on error_reporting and I got an error: Warning: file_put_contents (.htaccess): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/application/index.php on line 131.
Here is what line 131 of the index.php file contains:
$hta_res .= "RewriteEngine On\nRewriteBase /\nRewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]"; file_put_contents('.htaccess', $hta_res);

It seems it tries to write to .htaccess, which exists, should i give some priveleges to it?